# Align floating divs to the bottom

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this jsfiddl example: 
I want the left column to align to the bottom. 
Shouldn't be that hard but I can't make it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/magwalls/rdrznzhe/

```
<div width="100%" class="clear">
  <div class="fl" width="50%">I want this aligned to bottom</div>
    <div class="fr" width="50%">
      <div>Row 1</div>
      <div>Row 2</div>
      <div>Row 3</div>
    </div>    
</div>
<hr class="clear"/>
```

**EDIT:** I updated my JS Fiddle with Vitorinos and Dankos solutions to my problem here. http://jsfiddle.net/magwalls/rdrznzhe/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/rdrznzhe/9/)

```
.fl {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}

.wrap{
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}
```

added `.wrap` class for `<div width="100%" class="clear wrap">` (parent div) to clear the float of `.fr` or will taking `0px` height

Comment: `float: left;` Is no use on a postition absolute div. Use `left: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

As far I know you can't set the vertical alignment of `floated` elements, but you can try with `inline-block` and float other elements:

```
.fl, .fr {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:50%;
}
.fr > div {
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdrznzhe/8/)**

---

*Note if you use `inline-block` don't forget to remove the space [CSS TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) in this case I use the comment `<!-- -->`*

Comment: Only allowed to mark one answer. This is working just as good as the proposal from Vitorino.

Answer (score 0):

Let's lay this out with `display: table` and change your HTML slightly. We'll lay it out like this:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell left">I am going to be aligned at the bottom vertically</div>
    <div class="cell">I am going to contain three rows</div>
</div>
```

Now for the CSS. Tweak this as needed. In this example:

- `html,body { height: 100%; }` allows the wrapper div to have a percentage height
- The wrapper div is given `display: table`, `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`
- The two "columns" are given `display: table-cell` and act like columns
- The left column is given `vertical-align: bottom`
- `.cell > div` targets direct children of the `.cell` class. In this example, these divs are each given 33.33% height to evenly space them out into rows

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
}
.left {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: solid 1px #333;
    background: #DDD;
}
.cell > div {
    height: 33.33%;
    background: #EEE;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
}
.cell > div:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;  /* no border for that last child */  
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell left">I want this aligned to bottom</div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div>Row 1</div>
        <div>Row 2</div>
        <div>Row 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good example that might be useful but a bit overkill for my purpose.

Comment: Really? It's pretty straightforward :) You can change heights, widths. Doesn't need to span the entire page.